# The Simplest SwiftUI code fails in the preview

Tags: xcode, swiftui, arkit

This SWiftUI template code crashes the UI preview

```
    import SwiftUI

    struct SimplestTest: View {
        var body: some View {
           Text("Hello, World!")
       }
   }

    struct SimplestTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
       static var previews: some View {
           SimplestTest()
       }
   }
```

I realize this is at least partly because it's within an ARKit app with a UIController that looks like this

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, SCNSceneRendererDelegate, ARSessionDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
```

Which can't execute on a simulator

My intuition is that any SwiftUI code that is in an app that will only run on a device will crash the simulator.

Is this intuition correct? If not (& I do hope I'm wrong) how do I get the simulator to work with the simple piece of code that's part of the larger app?

This is my bare bones test. For "the real UIs" I tried solutions that provided the data from files etc. but they all crashed, so I scaled back to template code

Comment: Could be any number of things. Try doing Erase Content and Settings for all your Simulators

Comment: Tried (using xcrun simctl shutdown all & xcrun simctl erase all) that didn't make a difference -- I should have noted that the swiftui landmark example runs fine